# Should A Java Package Throws A Checked Exception of Its Dependency Module

Tags: java

I have a Java project which is divided into 3 modules. These three modules are separate Maven project but there is a dependency between them. The relationship is simple:

Module A depends on Module B

Module B depends on Module C

- Module C is a library which handles the low level database tasks like create session etc.
- Module B is a database library which defines DAOs, DTOs, Entities etc.
- Module A is a Restful Web Service which contains the business logic and uses library B to access the DB.

I have a checked exception defined in Module C which is thrown by a public method. Module B can get this Exception.

My question is that whether it is a good practice for B to

1. Catch this checked exception and throw another checked exception defined locally in Module B to module A.
2. Not catch the checked exception but declare this exception in its public method so that it is passed to module A.

My personal opinion is that a module should only throw a checked exception it defines to its client modules unless is the Java's predefined exception. But there is certainly an draw back of this which means I have to create two different exceptions in multiple modules to represent a same error condition.

Can anyone share your opinion?

Answer (score 2):

I would worry less about throwing exceptions and more about handling them.

Exceptions should be *exceptional*.  They should be caught only when they are handled appropriately.  If you can't handle, do nothing if it's an unchecked exception or catch and re-throw if it is.

Some modules should never, ever throw exceptions.  I'm thinking of UI controllers, because a user has a bad experience if they see a stack trace.  I'm also thinking of web services, because HTTP doesn't know or care about your exceptions.

Your error handling strategy should not revolve around exceptions.  You can send codes between modules and have a contract for handling them.

Logging is *not* handling.

I couldn't advise you on what do to based on what you've posted.  I'd want to know more about what the modules are doing.

Comment: Thanks. What I mean is checked exception. Edited original post.

Comment: Thanks. Edited the original post to give more about what each module does.

Answer (score 2):

I look at this from a type coupling perspective. If module B completely encapsulates the types in module C from module A then definitely do not introduce a type coupling between A and C just for an exception. If module B already exposes C's types to A (i.e. A is directly dependent on C as well as via its dependency on B) then go ahead and throw C's exceptions.